# python subprocess: order of output changes when using subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, python-3.5

When I write a python script called `outer.py` containing

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['./inner.py'])
print('Called inner.py without options, waiting for process...')
p.wait()
print('Waited for inner.py without options')

p = subprocess.Popen(['./inner.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print('Called inner.py with PIPE, communicating...')
b_out, b_err = p.communicate()
out = b_out.decode('utf8')
print('out is "{}"'.format(out))
```

And an `inner.py` containing

```
print("inner: Echoing Hallo")
p = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hallo'])
print("inner: Waiting for Echo to finish...")
p.wait()
print("inner: Waited for Echo")
```

I get the following when calling `outer.py` from a terminal:

```
Called inner.py without options, waiting for process...
inner: Echoing Hallo
inner: Waiting for Echo to finish...
hallo
inner: Waited for Echo
Waited for inner.py without options

Called inner.py with PIPE, communicating...
out is "hallo
inner: Echoing Hallo
inner: Waiting for Echo to finish...
inner: Waited for Echo
"
```

Why, when calling `inner.py` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, does the "hallo" appear before the "inner: Echoing Hallo" in the captured output?

Comment: cannot reproduce on my mac - however I had to add the shebang and import statements for the code to work in the first place. Please include a complete example as well as the operating system you are using.

Comment: Sounds like it could be buffering on standard out of inner.py.  Can you try disabling buffering, for instance with setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED?  More techniques listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/1062499

Comment: Communicate not single loop action and always returned string, not output !

Comment: @wildwilhelm You are right, when I disable output buffering the output is displayed in the same order as the corresponding statements in the script. But why is the behaviour different depending on how inner.py is called from outer.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that, for some reason (related to pipes vs. ttys, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering/107717#comment24604506_107717)), the output of the `inner.py` Python process is unbuffered the first time you call it, and buffered the second time you call it.  The first time, with unbuffered output, you get the result in the expected order written to your tty.  The second time, with buffering, the output from the `echo` command gets flushed first (because `echo` runs and terminates), and then all of the output from the `inner.py` process shows up at once, when `python` terminates.  If you disable output buffering for `inner.py`, you should get the same output in both cases.

Disable output buffering by setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable, or by calling python with the `-u` switch, or by explicitly calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print` (or `print(...,  flush=True)` on Python 3).

The difference between the behaviour of pipes and ttys seems to be a [general behaviour of `stdio`](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering): output to ttys is line-buffered (so, in your code, which reads line by line, it will seem to be unbuffered), whereas output to pipes is buffered.